# Open current bash location explicitly in Finder

Tags: mac, finder, terminal.app, bundle

When double clicking a bundle folder (folder called *.bundle), a Terminal window opens as expected. However,

> $ open .

does not then open a Finder window but another Terminal.

Is there a way to tell the open command to explicitly use the Finder as app?

Comment: Theoretically, there is a option to do this: "$ open . -a [application]". That doesn't work with simply typing "Finder"/"finder", though.

Comment: Should be possible with AppleScript's `tell application "Finder" to open folder …`, but I'm not sure on the details – not on a Mac right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `open -R` to reveal the bundle directory in Finder:

```
open -R .
```

It selects the bundle directory but doesn't show the package contents. This shows the package contents in list view and icon view but not in column view:

`osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"' -e reopen -e 'set target of Finder window 1 to POSIX file (system attribute "PWD")' -e activate -e end`

Comment: Cool, have just set up my 37signals/sub to do that for me